# Kirschenhofer Ramanujan functional equations part I I

Tags: calculus

it is possible to show the following identity,numerically it seem equal
$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \text{sech}^4(\pi  k x)=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{4 k^3 \text{csch}\left(\frac{\pi  k}{x}\right)}{3 x^4}+\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{4 k \text{csch}\left(\frac{\pi  k}{x}\right)}{3 x^2}+\frac{2}{3 \pi  x}-\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is also a consequence of the [Poisson summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula), since the Fourier transform of $f(x)=\text{sech}(\pi x)^4$ is given by:

$$ \widehat{f}(s) = C\cdot \frac{s(4\pi^2+s^2)}{\sinh(s/2)}.$$

Comment: Yes Jack i check it possible to get it making some calculations

Comment: So, mistery solved :)